# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Spring security 4.0

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I have created security for my rest services and I have used custom filter for authentication using "AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter" here are my configs.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="personDetailsService">
     <security:password-encoder base64="true" hash="md5">  
        <security:salt-source user-property="username"/>  
      </security:password-encoder>  
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http  entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
        use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" >
    <security:custom-filter ref="myAppAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>   
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/my/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <security:logout />
</security:http>
<bean class="my.web.auth.AppTokenAuthenticationFilter"
    id="myAppAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="requestMatcher"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="my.web.auth.PersonDetailService"  id ="personDetailsService"></bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher" id="requestMatcher">
 <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/my/**"></constructor-arg>

</bean>
<bean class="my.web.auth.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" id ="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
</bean>
</beans>
```

With this configuration my requests or keep on forward to filter after my SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler called. Even its not working with permitAll in intercept URL.